# Why the value assign inside the useEffect is not global?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Can you help me to understand, why the value assign inside the useEffect is not global?

Please see code below:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import "./App.css";

function App() {
  let value;

  useEffect( () => {
    value = 2
  }, []);

  console.log("Value: ", value)

  return (
    <>
    { value }
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: "Global" to what? The `value` variable is in function body scope. Or are you asking why the rendered result is that `value` is still `undefined`?

Comment: Global in the sense to use it outside the function. Yes why it is still undefined? @DrewReese.

Comment: Well, that is simply the way scope works in Javascript. `value` is only defined within the `App` function. It's undefined because the `useEffect` hook runs at the end of the render cycle, so mutations won't be rendered.

Comment: `return ( <> { value } </> )` is the long-winded way of saying `return value`

Answer (score 4):

Re-assigning value does not cause a re-render, additionally, every render cycle, value is reset to undefined. What you want is something like:

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import "./App.css";

function App() {
  const [value, setValue] = useState();

  useEffect( () => {
    setValue(2)
  }, []);

  console.log("Value: ", value)

  return (
    <>
    { value }
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```